# Parse simple JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I have a trouble to parse this piece of JSON

```
{
  "00408C88A2E6": {
    "id": "00408C88A2E6",
    "name": "pippo"},
    "00408C91188B": {
      "id": "00408C91188B",
      "name": "pluto"
    },
    "00408C944B99": {
      "id": "00408C944B99",
      "name": "minni"
    },
    "00408C944BA0": {
      "id": "00408C944BA0",
      "name": "topolino"
    }
```

I need to get all the key "id" and "name", I tried with an iterator but I was able to retrive just the first dicts (00408C88A2E6,00408C91188B...), could anyone give me any hint? 
Thank you

Edit:
I'm using org.json and to parse this I tried in this way

```
            JSONObject jsonChannels = getHttpJson(url_user_cam);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, jsonChannels.toString());

    try{
        Iterator<String> iterator =  jsonChannels.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext() ){
            al.add(iterator.next());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

with this piece of code my intent is to get the first dict ("00408C88A2E6") after make it I need to access to "id" and "name" element, hwo can i do it?

Comment: Looks like the JSON example is incomplete (2 closing braces are missing).  Also, are you using a library to parse the JSON?  jsonlib?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to parse it.  Which library?

Comment: What are you using to de-serialize the JSON data?

Comment: To be sure: aren't you confusing Java with JavaScript? If you were using Java, it would have been *too* obvious to mention which JSON library you're using because it's not builtin in Java SE and there are a lot of them. But since you're not mentioning it ...

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, it looks like your JSON is incomplete. Maybe a pasting error ?

Do you do it manually or do you use a library ?

Have you tried using the "official" [Java JSON package](http://www.json.org/java/) ?